# One Way Encryption and Decryption Acting Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, encryption

I have two functions that should encrypt and decrypt a given file:

```cs
        public static void Encrypt(string name, string skey)
        {
            using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(name))
            using (var destinationStream = File.Create(name + ".sav"))
            using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            using (var cryptoTransform = provider.CreateEncryptor())
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(destinationStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                provider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                List<byte> key = new List<byte>();
                key.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey));
                while (key.Count < 32)
                {
                    key.Add(0);
                }
                provider.Key = key.ToArray();
                destinationStream.Write(provider.IV, 0, provider.IV.Length);
                sourceStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            }
        }

        public static void Decrypt(string name, string skey)
        {
            // Decrypt the source file and write it to the destination file.
            using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(name + ".sav"))
            using (var destinationStream = File.Create(name))
            using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                provider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                List<byte> key = new List<byte>();
                key.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey));
                while(key.Count < 32)
                {
                    key.Add(0);
                }
                var IV = new byte[provider.IV.Length];
                sourceStream.Read(IV, 0, IV.Length);
                using (var cryptoTransform = provider.CreateDecryptor(key.ToArray(), IV))
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(sourceStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Using the text document (d):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Game xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <username>d</username>
  <superSecretString>foo</superSecretString>
</Game>
```

The following program:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pass = "foo";
            Encrypt("d", pass);
            Decrypt("d", pass);
        }
```

Results in the text document (d):

```
豄襚釞뮲冋ⵂૠɥ摸▪穨嶾⏘ﳿ僣ꙍ帏પ軆ꝍ遨䄩䰀玢⊟尩㯇Ўꉚ파 駧㪡襻긗몸뵊➯턊鏶㠌늸㗐蕛貣ㆪⲫ咻ꨱ壉뷢䅱眡�׀罹吗඘㶝�晊垚猰Ġ�淧脽ᣉ赮榑㄁舎㈁쾹͂쵎숵戥힠┻蔦쬦눲ꔲ빬䁔㸻�ⵄ➞ޅ㥿࠾ऱ룮﫪２侚神ヵ튙腶㖮衦ྗ
```

It seems that decrypting the message is causing the unexpected result however I don't what I should expect in the "*.sav" files besides random noise. Checking the watchlist `provider.key` is an array that reads out `102, 111, 111, 0 ... 0` in both `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods.

Comment: OK, so this is using CBC mode encryption (OK-ish for in place encryption), a random IV prefixed to the ciphertext (good) and no padding (bad). However, the error is clearly not padding related. I have a bit of a problem with the order of first creating a provider, then creating a stream, and then initiating the provider. That doesn't sound entirely right. Otherwise I don't see any direct error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes This is made to encrypt data in a game so perfect encryption is not necessary just enough to deter anyone from finding the contents in a reasonable amount of time. Should I move the `using(cryptoTransform...` and `using(cryptoStream...` before `using(provider...` then initialize those three in the brackets?

Comment: I don't have a C# IDE available at the moment, it's certainly something I would try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so your problem is that you are creating Encryptor but never set it's IV.

Change the `Encrypt` method like so:

```
public static void Encrypt(string name, string skey)
    {
        // First, process key
        List<byte> key = new List<byte>();
        key.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey));
        while (key.Count < 32)
        {
            key.Add(0);
        }

        using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(name))
        using (var destinationStream = File.Create(name + ".sav"))
        using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var cryptoTransform = provider.CreateEncryptor(key.ToArray(), provider.IV)) // when creating Encryptor pass the key and the IV of the provider.
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(destinationStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            provider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            provider.Key = key.ToArray();
            destinationStream.Write(provider.IV, 0, provider.IV.Length);
            sourceStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, this seems correct, but I'm still a bit amazed since `destinationStream.Write(provider.IV, 0, provider.IV.Length);` in the original code should write the correct IV. Apparently it doesn't; possibly it is generated right before the encryption (?). Oh, well, better to set it explicitly anyway, I don't like those kind of defaults.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the IV is set on the provider but not on the encryptor. It’s a bit confusing if you are doing it for the first time, but essentially the provider ‘provides’ the IV but it is for you to use one.